# Credential: "include", browser didn't send back cookie from the server

Tags: express, cors, httprequest, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I was using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) query with the option of `"credentials": "include"` to send cookies with my fetch requests.

Here my set up:

```js
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: `${import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER}`,
  prepareHeaders(headers) {
    return headers;
  },
  credentials: "include",
});

export const baseApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
})
```

When I made a post request to login, I received `"Set-Cookie"` header from the server

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0Yzg4OTU1YWUxODgwZjJmYzM1NmNjMSIsImlhdCI6MTY5MDg2NTIyMiwiZXhwIjoxNjkwODY2MTIyfQ.X_jNxlInBjaIkqevoaryDYDxSC15Qc9YBNjgdM9XpOs; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 308
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Any subsequent requests didn't include the header Cookie
header from client for example:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: vi-VN,vi;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that your server is not accessed via a secure URL (it's running on `http://localhost:3000`) and its response attempts to set a cookie marked `Secure`. Browsers reject such attempts. Only secure origins (in practice, those starting with `https://`) are allowed by browsers to set secure cookies.

Comment: @jub0bs thanks for your answer. What should i do for http://localhost:3000 then?